# htaccess replace domain but retain file and querystring

Tags: .htaccess

I need to create the following rewrites... Have tried a number of solutions but cant seem to get it working.

i am looking to change;

http://www.domain1.com/questionnaires/anyfile.php?q=anyquery

to

http://www.domain2.com/questionnaires/anyfile.php?q=anyquery

where it retains both the filename and any querys attached

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple redirect rule in the site root .htaccess of `domain1`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Note that query string is automatically carried forward in a redirect.